# check the content of $PATH and add ~/.local/bin in your .bashrc if neccessary

Tags: bash

I used Ubuntu to install software, but I can not find it.

Someone told me :

**pip --user installs things into a directory called ~/.local/bin, but this might not be on your bash search path.**

**Can you check the content of $PATH and add ~/.local/bin in your .bashrc if neccessary.**

How can I write the command?

Thanks in advance for any great help!

Best,

Yue

`li@li-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:/usr/local/bin$ ls
deploytool matlab mbuild mcc mex pcre-config pcregrep pcretest`

Comment: Why don't you do so manually?

Comment: Hello, MisterMiyagi, Thank you for your response. Do you have any idea how I can do it?Desktop-590-p0xxx:~/umi_tools-1.0.0$ umi_tools --help
umi_tools: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to the end of `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

It's almost certainly not worth worrying if this adds a duplicate entry to the path.

Comment: Hello, chepner,  Thank you so much for your great help! Thank you again! You give me great help!

Answer (score 0):

`echo $PATH` will check the current value of the PATH variable

Comment: Hello, Ben, Thank you so much for your quick response! How I can echo $PATH?Thanks in advance!